# UITableViewCell slow to react on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've created a `UITableView` with cells that contain a fairly large number of `UIView` objects. However when I select a cell, it doesn't seem to be smooth on running the segue. The second observation is that if I quickly double tap on a cell, it will run the segue twice (push view twice).

What could cause this behaviour? I'm using the phone as a test environment and all other apps are closed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //PickerView
    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.pickerView.interitemSpacing = 60
    self.pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#1C1F27")
    self.pickerView.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#D8D8D8").colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
    self.pickerView.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.pickerView.font = UIFont(name: "MavenProRegular", size: 12)!
    self.pickerView.highlightedFont = UIFont(name: "MavenProRegular", size: 12)!
    self.pickerView.pickerViewStyle = .StyleFlat
    self.pickerView.maskDisabled = false
    self.pickerView.reloadData()

    //Tableview
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    //ActivityIndicator
    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

//TABLEVIEW METHODS
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 140
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MatchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default

    let backgroundSelectionView = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
    backgroundSelectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.05)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundSelectionView

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("CameraController", sender: self)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: maybe your CameraController takes a bit longer to load, try to segue it to a normal viewcontroller and see whether it is smooth.

Comment: so if this is the issue, what would the solution be? to put things in the background threads?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. Generally I think you can try to move your code in viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear if it does not necessarily in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Another issue I have once experienced is that, if your CameraController is a tableView, and it loads a lot of cells with calculated height, it will also takes time to load.

Comment: the cameraController is an custom cameraView with and pageViewController on top of it.

Comment: I cant give any suggestion without looking the code. But if change to a normal view controller helps, it is the CameraController's issue. So try to refactor it.

Answer (score -1):

```
let backgroundSelectionView = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
```

You can put the view in the cell file.
Since tableViewCells are getting reused, once they created the cell (with the view) it will not be generated again.

On the other hand, what you are doing is every time you dequeue a cell, you initialize a view and assign it as a subview of the cell, which means you are doing extra view initialization work.

So you can go to the cell.m file and add a property for the view you need. If you are using storyboard for both tableview and cell, just do an IBOutlet there. If you are using xib file, just go there and do an IBOutlet there.

On the other hand, I have no clue what your camera view controller is doing. Maybe the instantiation is causing the performance issue. You may provide more code on the camera VC.